# How to change luks encryption difficulty on manjaro full disk encrypt

Tags: encryption, luks, manjaro

I am using manjaro with full disk encrypt, however, the wait time at boot for decrypt is very long ( i assume because of a high difficulty setting) . How can I change encryption difficulty/ wait time of the encryption setup during install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Too much passphrase hashing?

If it's only slow because you're waiting for a lot of passphrase hashing iterations, you could add a new passphrase with a quicker `--iter-time`, but that could reduce security & allow faster guessing of passphrases. If you wanted to wait 1 second (1000ms) then use a command like:

```
cryptsetup -v luksAddKey --iter-time 1000 <device>
```

You might then have to delete the old slow passphrase (with `luksKillSlot`), unless it's key slot is after the new quick one (they're apparently tested in order, so might have to wait for the first slow slot to be tested before the later quick one). Or change your initial open command to specify the new quicker `--key-slot` number.

The `luksChangeKey` command can combine the two steps, adding a new key then deleting the old key (even though the v1.7 man page doesn't specifically say it can use `--iter-time`, apparently it can):

```
cryptsetup -v luksChangeKey --iter-time 1000 <device>
```

## How slow is it now?

Test how long it takes to decrypt / open your device with:

```
cryptsetup -v luksOpen --test-passphrase <device>
```

Or test a specific key slot with the `--key-slot` option:

```
cryptsetup -v luksOpen --test-passphrase --key-slot N <device>
```

Using the `time` command might help, but also count your typing speed.

You can use the `luksDump` command to see what the current key slot `Iterations:` are, this is an example of a very slow slot 0 and a very quick slot 1:

```
Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             4663017
    Salt:                   ......
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: ENABLED
    Iterations:             1000
    Salt:                   ......
    Key material offset:    264
    AF stripes:             4000
```

---

From `man cryptsetup`:

> - `--iter-time`, `-i`
>
>   The  number  of  milliseconds  to  spend  with PBKDF2 passphrase processing.  This
>               option is only relevant for LUKS operations that set or change  passphrases,  such
>               as  luksFormat  or  luksAddKey.  Specifying 0 as parameter selects the compiled-in
>               default.
> - `luksChangeKey <device> [<new key file>]`
>
>   Changes an existing passphrase. The passphrase to  be  changed  must  be  supplied
>               interactively or via --key-file.  The new passphrase can be supplied interactively
>               or in a file given as positional argument.
>
>   If a key-slot is specified (via --key-slot), the passphrase for that key-slot must
>               be  given and the new passphrase will overwrite the specified key-slot. If no key-
>               slot is specified and there is still a free key-slot, then the new passphrase will
>               be  put  into a free key-slot before the key-slot containing the old passphrase is
>               purged. If there is no free key-slot, then the key-slot with the old passphrase is
>               overwritten directly.
>
>   **WARNING:**  If  a key-slot is overwritten, a media failure during this operation can
>               cause the overwrite to fail after the old passphrase has been wiped and  make  the
>               LUKS container inaccessible.

## It's not the passphrase hashing?

- There's lots of reasons for a slow boot time, maybe it's unrelated to the encryption.

Or if the actual encryption/decryption itself is too slow, then changing the algorithm or key size might be required, and that would require decrypting and re-encrypting everything. There are programs (or commands in newer versions) that can do it in-place, hopefully without losing anything, but having a backup would be more than an excellent idea.

But in that case, it wouldn't just be a long initial wait but all reads & writes would be a little slower.

You can use the `cryptsetup -v benchmark` command to see some speed tests, but *"NOTE: This benchmark is using memory only and is  only  informative.   You  cannot
              directly predict real storage encryption speed from it."*

Comment: Only problem i now have is the message "No key with this passphrase. Passphrase required to access luks volume...." after creating a new slot, and deleting the old. There were two slots occupied, and I deleted both, and added only one new... could this be the problem? I am able to unlock by typing the password twice (once in grub, and another after grub...)

Comment: That's worrying... if you use the `--key-slot` option for open then it only checks that slot, so maybe it's because *"If  the  given passphrase would only match a different key-slot, the operation fails."* But it does eventually unlock...  I don't know why it's asking twice, unless that's just how manjaro is set up? I'm not sure, maybe it was storing the passphrase somewhere else on disk and now it's changed, or maybe there's two encrypted partitions? Keeping a header backup is in general always a good idea, or possibly even a `--dump-master-key` if you're worried about losing all  passphrases